# Compactness Invariant between normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional normed spaces. Let $D:\X \rightarrow Y$ be an isometric isomorphism then if $X$ is compact the $Y$ is also compact.

I have started by choosing a sequence in $Y$ and then taking its inverse image but I am stuck.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is something wrong with your question.A normed space can not be compact, Since compactness implies bounded and closed. Can a normed space be bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Chival mentioned in the comments that a normed space cannot be bounded (since it is a vector space).
Rephrasing the question to overcome this issue, we get

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional normed spaces. Let $D:X \to Y$ be an isometric isomorphism. Prove that if $Z \subset X$ is compact then $D(Z)$ is also compact.

Then, by noticing $D$ is continuous, the conclusion follows, because as stated by Frank in another answer the following theorem holds:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, and if $X$ is compact, then $Y$ is compact.

Answer (score -2):

Look up the following (more general) theorem: If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, and if $X$ is compact, then $Y$ is compact.

Comment: So since $D$ is continuous and onto, $D(X)=Y$ and since $X$ is compact, $Y$ is compact??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much!

Comment: Could you maybe upvote and accept my answer? Someone has downvoted it, though I am certain this is correct!!!

Comment: @davim1992, do you guys really think that a normed space can be compact ?

Comment: Nope, but that's (in a logically technical sense) irrelevant. I show that if $X$ was compact, then $Y$ would be too. It doesn't matter that $X$ can never be compact!!! So I don't think my answer should be punished. Only the question!

Comment: And if the question was just changed for a compact subset of X and its image under f (as I guess I parsed the question in my mind),  everything would be ok.

Comment: Sorry! I was supposed to be showing that a subset was compact. Sorry for any confusion!